# find the value of 4(r+s) for the following question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The numbers $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{ln(y)}{3ln(x)}$, $\frac{ln(z)}{3ln(y)}$, $\frac{ln(x)}{7ln(z)}$ are in HP (Harmonic progression). If $y = x^r$ and $z=x^s$, then find the value of 4(r+s).

Comment: Use $$\ln y=r\ln x, \ln z=s\ln x\implies s\ln y=r\ln z$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing the given terms in terms of $r,s$, and multiplying by $3$, we get that $1,r,\frac sr,\frac{3}{7s}$ are in HP. Hence, their reciprocals, which are $1,\frac 1r, \frac rs, \frac{7s}{3}$ are in arithmetic progression.

This means that $1 + \frac rs = \frac 2r$ ,and $1 + \frac {7s}3 = \frac 1r + \frac rs$.

From this, we see that $\frac 3r = 1 +\frac 1r + \frac rs = 2 + \frac{7s}3$.  Simplifying, we get that $r(6+7s) = 9$.

Substituting for $7s$, we get $1 + \frac {\frac 9r-6}3 = \frac 1r + \frac rs$, so that $\frac 3r - 1 = \frac 1r + \frac rs$. This gives us $\frac 2r = 1 + \frac{r}{s}$, or $s = \frac{r^2}{2-r}$.

Hence, $\frac 9r - 6 = \frac{7r^2}{2-r}$. Simplifying, $(9-6r)(2-r) = 7r^3$, and further simplifying, $(r^2+3)(7-6r) = 0$ (to get this, expand and then collect terms). This gives $r = \frac 67$, $ s = \frac{9}{14}$ and the required quantity as $6$.

Comment: answer is 6. the value of r is 6/7 and that of s is 9/14. i have very very long method of about more than 2 pages.

Comment: you may be right because your answer is very nearer to 6.

Comment: I have spotted a mistake, in my calculation. I will get back to you.

Comment: Please check my work now.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$\frac{\ln y}{3\ln x}=\frac{\ln x^r}{3\ln x}=\frac{r\ln x}{3\ln x}=\frac r3;$$
$$\frac{\ln z}{3\ln y}=\frac{\ln x^s}{3\ln x^r}=\frac{s\ln x}{3r\ln x}=\frac{s}{3r};$$
$$\frac{\ln x}{7\ln z}=\frac{\ln x}{7\ln x^s}=\frac{\ln x}{7s\ln x}=\frac{1}{7s}.$$

Thus, the harmonic progression is:
$$\frac 13, \frac r3, \frac{s}{3r}, \frac{1}{7s}.$$

> Note that for the harmonic progression $a,b,c,d$, each term is the harmonic mean of the neighboring terms:$$b=\frac{2ac}{a+c}; \ \ \ c=\frac{2bd}{b+d}.$$

Hence:
$$\begin{cases} \frac r3=\frac{\frac{2s}{9r}}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{s}{3r}} \\ \frac{s}{3r}=\frac{\frac{2r}{21s}}{\frac{r}{3}+\frac{1}{7s}}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} r^2+sr-2s=0 \\ 6r^2-7s^2r-3s=0\end{cases}.$$
Now $s=\frac{r^2}{2-r}$ from $(1)$ substitute in $(2)$: 
$$\\ 6r^2-7\cdot \frac{r^4}{(2-r)^2}\cdot r-3\cdot \frac{r^2}{2-r}=0 \Rightarrow $$
$$7r^3-6r^2+21r-18=0 \Rightarrow $$
$$r^2(7r-6)+3(7r-6)=0 \Rightarrow$$
$$(r^2+3)(7r-6)=0 \Rightarrow r=\frac 67$$
Hence:
$$s=\frac{r^2}{2-r}=\frac{9}{14}.$$
And finally:
$$4(r+s)=6.$$

Comment: correct answer is 6. r=6/7 and s=9/14.